# Overriding CSV Export default settings on asp.net mvc +stimulsoft

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I'm using the stimulsoft mvc report viewer, on an asp.net mvc4 app.  I am trying to figure out how to override the default settings for encoding and separator, so that my end users don't have to change them.

In particular, I need to know how to go about accessing the StiCsvExportSettings object.  I also need to know the correct place in the code to put it (on the viewer, or the report setup callback).

I can't find any documentation on how this should be done.

Does anybody have any experience with this concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to do in current version. This feature will be available in one of next prerelease builds.